# Laravel Blade Recommended Design

Tags: css, laravel, uinavigationbar, laravel-blade, sidebar

I'm Laravel Newbie.
I would like to convert my Dreamweaver template to Laravel Blade.
There are a header, left-sidebar and right-content.
The header has a navigation bar with dropdown function.

Each navigation bar button is the one category.
Once click on the button, the sidebar will change.
Diff category has their own sidebar.
Each sidebar contains submenu.

Is it not only Blade's topic but also CSS topic?

Please advice.

Comment: Please describe the specific problem you are having. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

It's Blade, CSS and probably backend topic as well (depending on what's powering your site at the moment).
You could create a master template (where you'd place header, footer, etc.)
A template for the sidebar and another template for the main content (these two templates would come included in your master template).